# how can I paint hair particles?

Tags: texturing, particles, texture-painting, weight-painting, hair

what I am trying to do is not to make the hair bleed like what you see in the photos so it's like projecting the colors on the hair particles

what's happening here is the hair particles taking the color from the base texture and because the hair is long the color continues to bleed and I don't want that I want the color to stay in the spot

it's fine if the hair is standing street and short but because I am combing the hair and it's long it's bleeding I hope I made that clear

please let me know how to fix this

thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want the color at the base of the hair particle to not be consistent along the length of the hair. Is that correct?

Comment: not only at the base I just want the color to be at this spot so even the hair that comes from above to have white color, so like projecting the color on the hair, if you watch Monsters, Inc  I want to make the hair like James P. Sullivan you see the hair on him not bleeding like on my hair

Comment: basically it's like spray paint the hair

Comment: That’s what I thought. You should edit your question to say that. “Bleeding” sounds like something is wrong, but real hair is not like what you’re asking for. I’m not sure most people will have an idea of what “bleeding” means in this context, but if you say “I want hair color to look like a pattern was spray-painted onto it, I.e. color should not be consistent along individual particles, since they will be too long to keep the pattern looking right if it did that,” or something along those lines.